# Django 2.2 staticfiles do not work in development

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-deployment

I'm making a new django app where a user can upload images and then they can be displayed on a page. I've read the django docs 10000 times through and I still don't understand why my images aren't loading (DEBUG = True)

All my images are going to where they're supposed to be and in the admin in my models django has the right path that leads to the image but it just won't load properly.

my setup in settings.py:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static' # live cdn such as AWS S3

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/img/'
```

my directories:

```
|- src
    |- myproject
        |- settings.py, views.py, urls.py etc
    |- myapp
        |- views.py urls.py models.py forms.py etc
    |- static (this folder is empty and appeared after running collectstatic
    |- templates
    |- db.sqlite3
    |- manage.py
|- static (this folder is OUTSIDE src)
    |- admin
        |- django admin stuff
    |- media
        |- img
            |- myimage.png
```

in models.py of myapp the imagefield upload_to = 'img/'

as i said, the images don't load on the page but to upload to static/media/img/image_name.png

I've been trying to fix this for ages but i can't get any help from anyone and django docs and other stackoverflow questions/answers have been of no help too.

I thank you for your help!

Comment: you did not create the media url in your urls.py

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: what? how do i do that? that's nowhere in the django docs?!

Comment: scroll to the middle of the document. it is right there

Comment: Like I have said in the first comment, you do not have media url in your urls.py. and that has been explained in the documentation.

Comment: Post your `urls.py` if you are in doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Serving files uploaded by a user during development¶
>
> During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from
>   MEDIA_ROOT using the django.views.static.serve() view.
>
> This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment
>   strategies, see Deploying static files.
>
> For example, if your MEDIA_URL is defined as /media/, you can do this
>   by adding the following snippet to your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` denotes where Django will look for your static files, this is where you should be putting you static files so that they will be served in development and be collected from by collectstatic when you deploy.

Looks like you have set this to `src/static` so this is where you should be putting your static files.

`STATIC_ROOT` is where your static assets will be collected to after you have run collectstatic

[`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) by default will look in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and every `app/static` directory

A typical layout is like this

```
project_root/
    project_name/
        settings.py
        urls.py
        static/ < This is usually STATICFILES_DIRS
    app_1/
        models.py
        views.py
        static/ < AppDirectoriesFinder will look here
    app_2/
        models.py
        views.py
        static/ < AppDirectoriesFinder will look here
    static/ < This is where assest will be collected by collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in fact, I didn't specifed my static files in my `nginx.conf`.

If it can help you: sometimes we forget to check our basic configuration :D